# The way of finding intersections of rotated rectangles

Tags: android, rotation, collision-detection, intersection, clipping

Is there any way of get information about intersection of Rect's while there are rotated by given angle? I know that normal function on rect `Rect.intersect()` isn't taking rotation into account.